Vulkan Error not support
My vulkan drive is not been used.
I am using kubuntu with amd R5 with m330 but while running games which requires vulkan support it crashes. I searched and saw error code that the vulkan drive is incompatible and been bot used
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Received return code -3 from call to vkCreateInstance in ICD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan virtio.so. Skipping this driver.
WARNING: [Loader Message] Code 0 : terminator_CreateInstance: Received return code -3 from call to vkCreateInstance in ICD /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so. Skipping this driver. 
ERROR: [../src/amd/vulkan/radv physical_device.c2010] Code 0 : Device '/dev/dri/renderD128' is not using the AMDGPU kernel driver: Invalid argument (VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER) 
ERROR: [../src/amd/vulkan/radv physical_devices:2010] Code 0 : Device '/dev/dri/renderD128' is not using the AMDGPU kernel driver: Invalid argument (VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER)

After some research I found that I have to use amdgpu instead of Radeon so I edited the grub
radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1

and it changed to amdgpu but I was not able to adjust brightness of laptop and the vulkan error was changed to radv error.
Is there any way to run vulkan on this hybrid GPU?
